# AddHttpContextAccessor in ConfigureServices vs per HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httpclientfactory

Is there any difference between adding the httpContextAccessor one time in ConfigureServices method versus adding the HttpContextAccessor per HttpClient configured.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

    // FIRST VERSION
    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

    // SECOND VERSION
    var myService1 = services.AddHttpClient<TestHttpClient1>(c =>
    {
        c.BaseAddress = new Uri(Configuration["TestHttpClient1"]);
    });
    myService1.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

    var myService2 = services.AddHttpClient<TestHttpClient2>(c =>
    {
        c.BaseAddress = new Uri(Configuration["TestHttpClient2"]);
    });
    myService2.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
}
```

My guess would be to think that in the second version, we have two singleton, one will be used for class TestHttpClient1 and the other one for TestHttpClient2 but I dont see why we do that because I saw this code in production.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is there any difference between adding the httpContextAccessor one time in ConfigureServices method versus adding the HttpContextAccessor per HttpClient configured.

No, there's no difference whatsoever. `myService1.Services` and `myService2.Services` both reference the *same* `IServiceCollection` as the `services` variable. The first call (`services.AddHttpContextAccessor()`) will register the service, but the next two calls (`myService1.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor()` and `myService2.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor()`) will *no-op* (do nothing).

To put that all in to context, here's an extract from the source code for `AddHttpClient<TClient>(...)` ([source](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/release/2.2/src/HttpClientFactory/Http/src/DependencyInjection/HttpClientFactoryServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L385-L388)):

```
var builder = new DefaultHttpClientBuilder(services, name);
// ...
return builder;
```

A new instance of `DefaultHttpClientBuilder` is created, which wraps up the `IServiceCollection` that's passed in. As this is an extension method, `services` here refers to the same `services` as in your `ConfigureServices` method. This is then exposed through [`IHttpClientBuilder.Services`](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/release/2.2/src/HttpClientFactory/Http/src/DependencyInjection/IHttpClientBuilder.cs#L21), which is what you're using when you reference e.g. `myService1.Services`.

The call to `AddHttpContextAccessor` uses `TryAddSingleton`, which will register the service only if it hasn't already been registered ([source](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/release/2.2/src/Http/Http/src/HttpServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L27)):

```
services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

In your example, it *has already been registered* by that first call to `services.AddHttpContextAccessor()`, which means the next two registration attempts do nothing.